# Go back to the beginning of switch (getch() ) in the default ? (c)

Tags: c, switch-statement, getch

I am currently coding in C and using switch & getch,
like this :

```
c=getch(); 
switch(c)
        {
            case 17: 
            //something
            break;

            case 19: 
            //something else
            break;

            default: //loop to get the right "case"
            break;

        }
```

However, I want to loop my switch in the case of we get into the "default". Does anything exist for that ? Or should I make a "while (x!=10)" -for example- looping my whole switch, and if I go into default, x==10??

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: you can use `goto`, but of the people discourage to use `goto`

Answer (score 6):

If you find `goto` distasteful, you can create a dummy loop and use `continue` after `default:` to force next loop iteration:

```
do {
  c = getch();
  switch(c) {
    case 17: 
      //something
      break;
    // ...
    default:
      continue;
  }
} while (false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use do-while loop,. For example

```
int done;

do
{
    done = 1;

    c =getch(); 
    switch( c )
    {
        case 17: 
        //something
        break;

        case 19: 
            //something else
            break;

        default: //loop to get the right "case"
            done = 0;
            break;
    }
} while ( !done );
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is discouraged by most of the programmers to use `goto`, because of hampering to keep track of the flow of the program, you can use it. The statements are syntactically valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
xx:
    c=getch();
    switch(c)
    {
    case 17:
        //something
        break;

    case 19:
        //something else
        break;

    default: //loop to get the right "case"
        goto xx;
        break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: goto is evil, especially as `do{}while()` would be a) as effective and b) more readable.

Comment: @nonchip sure, as OP mentioned about the while loop, I thought he could do it with loop and answer with loop would come straightforward. I also mentioned that it is discouraged, but it is good to know about `goto` in case of emergency.

Answer (score 1):

For best coding practices, just forget that the `goto` exists.

The following code does what you want

```
int  done = 0; // indicate not done
while( !done )
{
    done = 1; // indicate done
    //c=getch();  not portable, do not use
    c = getchar();

    switch(c)
    {
        case 17:
        //something
        break;

        case 19:
        //something else
        break;

        default: //loop to get the right "case"
            done = 0;  // oops, not done, so stay in loop
        break;
    } // end switch
} // end while
```